# Top: DATA = RES + stack + what?

Tags: memory, top, stack

I've analyzed memory consumption of a java program on Linux Mint. I used `top` to capture memory statistics (memory used by program and also system-wide indicators like total_mem_used and mem_free). The results were surprising:

- "used physical memory" (`RAM_USE_DELTA` on chart) increased and "free physical memory" (reverted `RAM_FREE_DELTA` on chart) decreased the same amount the RES (`P_RSS` on chart) increased - this is what I expected
- the DATA (`P_DATA` on chart) field (described in `top`'s man as "the amount of physical memory devoted to other than executable code") was 150 megs above RES.
- SWAP (`SWAP_USE_DELTA` on chart) was zero all the time
- SHR (shared memory; `P_SHR` on chart) was less than 15MB

The question is: what was counted in the aforementioned 150MB? Virtual (reserved but not allocated) stack? Memory mapped files? As I wrote before: `RES` ~ `RAM_USED_DELTA` so the amount of free memory did NOT decrease by 150MB so it may indicate virtual memory but it would be weird for a memory indicator to be a sum of a resident set and a virtual amount...

[image: memory usage chart]

(on this chart lines described `*_DELTA` are relative to the start of the program i.e. close to the left side, where red `P_RSS` starts)

Answer (score 0):

The field DATA is the virtual memory of the process allocated for stuff which is not executable code, that is to say, data; it includes static data, the stack, and dynamically allocated memory; together with the field CODE it is included in the total VIRTual memory. The RESident size is the amount of virtual memory which is actually in RAM; it consists of part of the CODE, part of the DATA and part of other things such as memory mapped files.

You will notice that there is no direct relationship between VIRT, CODE, DATA and RES. The CODE comes from the compiler; the VIRT and DATA are under the control of the process (`malloc()`, `free()`, `mmap()`, and so on); the RES part is controlled by the operating system.

Comment: 1. but VIRT is exactly 4399904 _all_ the time, doesn't change while DATA has a few 50MB increases. 2. I've already made a simple c program to check the VIRT and RES relation - it mallocs a lot of memory and either fills it or not so VIRT may be as high as I want and RES may still stay low. How can I keep DATA int the middle?

Comment: Thanks. You might be interested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478467/what-is-the-difference-between-used-and-virt